# How to OneToMany relation in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm not sure what I'm missing to make a onetomany relationship using JPA.

Field username_id in second table is created as MUL key, I'm expecting Foreign Key, what's wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userandpassword")
public class LoginAndPassword {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long username_id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String user_password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<GradeEntity> g;

//getters, setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "grades")
public class GradeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "grade")
    private String grade;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "username_id")
    private LoginAndPassword loginAndPassword;

//getters,setters
```

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. Here's the documentation on how to create and map a bidirectional one-to-many association: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `mappedBy` in the @OneToMany

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "loginAndPassword")
 List<GradeEntity> g;
```

Comment: Thank you I did it in past, but I used  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "LoginAndPassword") and this made error.
Why this mappedBy = "loginAndPassword" must start with a lowercase letter??

Comment: It should refer to the field name which is in lowercase

Comment: just to clarify, it should refer to the field that defines the `@JoinColumn`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to specify the

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "loginAndPassword", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<GradeEntity> g;
```

This is a good tutorial explaining the JPA and Hibernate OneToMany relationship mapping, I highly recommend you to check it out.

[JPA and Hibernate One To Many Relationship Mapping Example with Spring Boot and MySQL](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)